# Trigger when Jquery ui tabs is open for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Question is in the title, I'm looking for a solution to trigger only first time someone open a tab of jquery ui tabs. 
My problem is that I have a page with many execution of functions when you load it, I want to launch thoses functions only when the user open the tab for the first time, to save time on loading the page.
I try to use activate or beforeActivate but it's triggered each time you open the tabs and it's not what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance

EDIT : ADDING SOME CODE

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</li>            
        </ul>
        <div class="consultation" id="tabs-1">
            // Do some stuff with DataTable
        </div>
        <div class="consultation" id="tabs-2">
            // Do some stuff with Highcharts
        </div>
        <div class="consultation" id="tabs-3">
            // Do some stuff with Highcharts   
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is when the user load the page, there is a lot of JS / AJAX / PHP stuff to do for displaying my DataTable tab and my two Highchart graph. It's why I want to launch the loading of tab-2 and tab-3 only when the user open them for the first time.

Comment: Have a look at [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). And please provide some code, so it's easier for us to help

Comment: *" when the user open the tab for the first time"* - does this apply for the first tab which is open by default, or do you want to execute something when user actually activates a tab by clicking it..?

Comment: Yes I want to execute something when user activates a tab, but only the first time he do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-create` function, if it doesn't work for you you can simply use a boolean variable to ensure functions are executed only once